# Is there a way to install configuration profiles by code or cmd on MacOS Big Sur?

Tags: objective-c, macos, macos-big-sur

I use to connect 802.1x network by configuration profiles and install it by system cmd 'profiles' before.But Starting with macOS Big Sur, this cmd cannot be used to install configuration profiles. User should add profiles using the System Preferences panel.
This change is inconvenient to user at all,is there a way to install profiles more silent or convenient? May be by code or cmd?
I am also very curious how does System Preferences install profiles on Big Sur.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belong on https://apple.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @zrzka I disagree with closing this. It appears to be asking for a a programmatic way to load configuration profiles for a network. The Apple.stackexchange site has always been more user or admin oriented and not a great place for programming questions

Comment: There's no way, it's a new macOS Big Sur feature. Watch [What's new in managing Apple devices](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10639) (around 9:35). [Apple developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/) is more appropriate place to discuss this topic or let Apple know via [Feedback Assistant](http://feedbackassistant.apple.com/). If you feel that I'm wrong you can always flag my comment, cast reopen vote (3k rep required), ...